# efficient way to calculate distance between combinations of pandas frame columns

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, nlp

**Task**

I have a pandas dataframe where:

- the columns are document names
- the rows are words in those documents
- numbers inside the frame cells are a measure of word relevance (word count if you want to keep it simple)

I need to calculate a new matrix of doc1-doc similarity where:

- rows and columns are document names
- the cells inside the frame are a similarity measure, (1 - cosine distance) between the two documents

The cosine distance is conveniently provided by [script.spatial.distance.cosine](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html).

I'm currently doing this:

1. use itertools to create a list of all 2-combinations of the document names (dataframe columns names)
2. loop over these and create a update a dictionary of {doc1: {doc2: similarity}}
3. after the loop, create a new frame using pandas.DataFrame(dict)

**Problem**

But it takes a very very long time. The following shows current speed on a MacBook Pro 13 with 16GB ram and 2.9GHz i5cpu running latest anaconda python 3.5 ... plotting time taken against combinations of docs.

[image: distance calculation performance]

You can see that 100,000 combinations takes 1200 seconds. Extrapolating that to my corpus of **7944** documents, which creates 3**1,549,596** combinations, would take **5 days** to calculate this similarity matrix!

**Any ideas?**

- I [previously](http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/more-performance-memory-stuff-to-fix.html) was dynamically creating the dataframe df.ix[doc1,doc2]
  = similarity .. which was very very much slower.
- I've considered numba @git but it fails with pandas data structures.
- I can't find a built in function which will do all the work internally (in C?)
- What I have to do tactically is to randomly sample the documents to create a much smaller set to work with ... currently a fraction of 0.02 leads to about 20 minutes of calculation!

**Here's the code ([github](https://github.com/makeyourowntextminingtoolkit/makeyourowntextminingtoolkit/tree/master/text_mining_toolkit))**

```
docs_combinations = itertools.combinations(docs_sample, 2)
for doc1, doc2 in docs_combinations:
    # scipy cosine similarity function includes normalising the vectors but is a distance .. so we need to take it from 1.0
    doc_similarity_dict[doc2].update({doc1: 1.0 - scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(relevance_index[doc1],relevance_index[doc2])})
    pass

#convert dict to pandas dataframe
doc_similarity_matrix = pandas.DataFrame(doc_similarity_dict)
```

**Simple Example**

@MaxU asked for an illustrative example.

Relevance matrix (wordcount here, just to keep it simple):

```
...     doc1 doc2 doc3
wheel   2.   3.   0.
seat    2.   2.   0.
lights  0.   1.   1.
cake    0.   0.   5.
```

calculated similarity matrix based on 2-combinations (doc1, doc2), (doc2, doc3), (doc1, doc3)

```
...     doc2 doc3
doc1    0.9449  0.
doc2    -       0.052
```

Take that top left value 0.889 .. thats the dot product (2*3 + 2*2 + 0 + 0) = 10 but normalised by the lengths of the vectors ... so divide by sqrt(8) and sqrt(14) gives 0.9449. You can see that there is no similarity between doc1 and doc3 .. the dot product is zero.

Scale this from 3 documents with 4 words ... to **7944** documents, which creates 3**1,549,596** combinations ...

Comment: could you post a small reproducible sample data set (3-5 rows) and desired data set (both in __text__ form)?

Comment: @MaxU here's a blog post with a simplified example of the calculation I#m trying to do .. with plenty of diagrams too [grouping similar documents](http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/grouping-similar-documents-aka.html)

Comment: @MYOTextMiningToolkit maybe you can try to calculate the similarities using Local Sensitive Hashing, should be much more efficient.

Comment: @maxu .. I've added a sample calculation as requested

Comment: @JoãoAlmeida .. I will do that for the next part of. my project .. dimensionality reduction . thanks

Comment: @MYOTextMiningToolkit, please take a look at James's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) will be a good solution for this.  As I think you know, it does not support Pandas DataFrames, but it is built around NumPy arrays.  This is not a problem--you can easily and quickly convert your DataFrame to a 2D array and pass that to a Numba function (which will be pretty much the code you already have, just decorated with `@njit` at the top).

Also note that instead of a dict-of-dicts for the results, you can use one triangle of a square matrix to store them:

```
     doc1 doc2 doc3
doc1  NAN  NAN  NAN
doc2  ...  NAN  NAN
doc3  ...  ...  NAN
```

---

Edit: You've now implemented it using Numba, but got only a 2.5x speedup.  I ran some experiments and found a big win:

```
In [66]: x = np.random.random((1000,1000))

In [67]: y = np.array(x, order='F')

In [68]: %timeit similarity_jit(x)
1 loop, best of 3: 13.7 s per loop

In [69]: %timeit similarity_jit(y)
1 loop, best of 3: 433 ms per loop
```

That is, your algorithm will be much, much faster if you operate on contiguous chunks of data, due to caching.  Since the kernel of your algorithm is `numpy.dot(m[:,i], m[:,j])`, and `m[:,i]` takes one column, you are better off orienting your data in ["Fortran order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) (column-major order) first, so that `m[:,i]` gives one contiguous array (because the array is laid out "transposed" in memory).

Comment: I tried numba but the result is slower .. someone suggested that this is because the bumpy.linalg and the scipy libraries are already optimised.

Comment: here is my writeup of using numba ... to show a slowdown [http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/does-numba-help-improve-performance.html](http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/does-numba-help-improve-performance.html)

Comment: @MYOTextMiningToolkit: You made a mistake.  :)  You need to apply Numba to the outer loop which drives the calculations, not to the inner kernel which calls SciPy.  In other words, stop using itertools and use Numba to iterate through the inputs to your function.

Comment: thanks .. that suggestion seems to have improved the code by a factor of about 2.5x .. which is great because I now know that I should takeout the loop into the JIT section .. but sadly bringing down a projected 5 day processing time down to 2.5 days is still impractical... any other suggestions ... Cython? .. ps I've written up this new JIT experiment and results at the end of the previous [blog post](http://makeyourowntextminingtoolkit.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/does-numba-help-improve-performance.html)

Comment: that is an amazing optimisation .. dramatically improved performance .. see the updated blogpost for more graphs!

Comment: @MYOTextMiningToolkit: Wonderful.  When the data set is quite small it all fits in L3 cache and Fortran order doesn't help much all.  But it really pays off when the data doesn't fit in cache anymore.  I found similar effects when I tried it too.  Thank you for writing it all up.

Answer (score 2):

This is about as efficient as I can make an algorithm without moving into multiprocessing (bleh).  The function uses numpy arrays for all of the calculations.

```
def cos_sim(data_frame):
    # create a numpy array from the data frame
    a = data_frame.values
    # get the number of documents
    n = a.shape[-1]
    # create an array of size docs x docs to populate
    out = np.ravel(np.zeros(shape=(n, n)))

    for i in range(n):
        # roll the array one step at a time, calculating the cosine similarity each time
        r = np.roll(a, -i, axis=1)
        cs = np.sum(a[:,:n-i]*r[:,:n-i], axis=0) / (
                np.sqrt(np.sum(a[:,:n-i]*a[:,:n-i], axis=0))
                *np.sqrt(np.sum(r[:,:n-i]*r[:,:n-i], axis=0)))

        # push the cosine similarity to the output array's i-th off-diagonal
        out[i:n*n-i*n:n+1] = cs

    return out.reshape((n,n))
```

Comment: that code looks complex to an amateur like me .. I'd like to see if I can get simpler code working before look deeply at your rolling code...